# Appending to an SVG Group from a second data source

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I am trying to work on a project where I need to generate rows of grouped data and draw dots on based on Json data from two different files.

I need to place a series of dots initially and then add another series later upon a button push. For testing purposes I have two Json files: one for sales and one for Buys. Each file has two customers with nested data for sales or buys. I group by Company, drawing a red dot for each sale, with this code. This works very well:

```
function loadSVG() {
    //Load in GeoJSON data
    //d3.json("data/zzMonthlySalesAndBuysComb.json", function (json) {
    d3.json("data/zzMonthlySales2.json", function (json) {

        g = svg.append('g').classed("chart", true)
          .attr("width", w)
          .selectAll(".csMove")
          .data(json, function (d) { return d.CompanyName + d.Company; })
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .classed("csMove", true)
          //.attr({ width: w, height: 100  })
          //.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
              //return "translate(0," + h / 2 + ")";
          //})
          .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0, " + i * 100 + ")"; })
          .append("g")
          .classed("CustomerBox", true);

        //This test code 
        g.append("rect")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", function (d) { return h / 2; })
           .style("fill", "silver");

        var SalesDot = svg.selectAll(".CustomerBox").selectAll(".Sdot")
        //.data(json)
        .data(function (d) { return d.monthlySales })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("Sdot", true);

        //then we add the circles in the correct company group
        SalesDot
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function (d) { return ((d.month - 20130001) / 2); })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.sales })
           .attr("r", 5)
           .style("fill", "red");

        //Test - add dots initially

    });
}
```

This works great. but this is where it fails.  I have a button on the page and when I press the button I run this function which will load the buys data,  I just get just two green dots each at the 0, 0 coordinates of the two groups.

```
function AddToSVG() {

    //Load in GeoJSON data
    //d3.json("data/zzMonthlyBuys2.json", function (json2) {
    d3.json("data/zzMonthlyBuys2.json", function (json2) {

        //add Green Circles.
        var BuysDot = svg.selectAll(".CustomerBox").selectAll(".Bdot")

        .data(json2)
        //.data(function (d) { return d.monthlySales })
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("Bdot", true);

        //then we add the circles in the correct company group
        BuysDot
           .data(function (d) {
               return d.monthlyBuys;
           })
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function (d) {
               return ((d.monthBuys - 20130001) / 2);
           })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.buys })
           .attr("r", 5)

           .style("fill", "green");
    });
}
```

Specifically what is happening is that the system still sees d as having data from monthlySales rather than MonthlyBuys. I see this when I put a break point at `return d.monthlyBuys`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I need the Buys and MonthlyBuys to be drawn over the existing groups for the correct Customers.

Comment: The two pieces of code you use to add circles for sells and buys suggest a completely different data structure for the two (and it looks like adding the sales circles shouldn't work at all). Are you sure that you've posted the right code?

Comment: The Sales part works well, it is when I go to try and add the Buys data that I run into trouble.  The data is formatted like this:  

Sales Data:

    [

      {
  
        "Company": "1",
    
        "CompanyName": "Alpha",
    
        "monthlySales":
            [{
        
                "month":20130101,
        
                "Sales":58
      
            },
      
            {
        
                 "monthSales":20130201,
        
                 "Sales":38
      
            }]
  
       }
    ] 

Buys Data is structured the same only with MonthlyBuys  and MonthBuys and Buys

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: I have a working example @ [link](https://github.com/Alarond/D3TestDataJoin) https://github.com/Alarond/D3TestDataJoin

Comment: Ok, your nested selections are a bit confusing. You have the same at the top level (`.CustomerBox`) and different classes at the level below that. You're changing the data bound to `.CustomerBox` when you're getting the buy data, which is almost certainly not what you want (you're losing the sell data through that). In your `AddToSVG` function you're not using the nested selections properly (`.data()` should be preceded by `.selectAll()`). It's not clear to me what structure you're aiming for in the end.

Comment: I want to bind additional data to (.CustomerBox) from the second dataset json2.   I want to add (.Bdot) to (.CustomerBox) where the I added the (.Sdot) group before.  The result should be a series of both red and green dots along the same x point.

Comment: In that case I would modify the original data to include the new data such that your nested selection works.

Comment: Yes I came to that conclusion too.  However this is just a simplified mockup.   The actual app is much more complex with a much larger amount of data.  The use case is where we have a basic set of data being displayed but the user can then select a overlay of some other data.   There may, in the future be several different options with different dataSets so we need to find a way to add new datasets with out pulling all possible datasets up front.

Comment: Well you wouldn't need to get all possible datasets up front, you just need a way of merging incoming data with the data you got before.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem.   I added to each group it's own ID = companyName  - > .attr("id", function (d) { return d.CompanyName; })

Then I was able to access that group with svg.select('#' + company.CompanyName).selectAll(".Sdot") 

The updated code is at GitHob - https://github.com/Alarond/D3TestDataJoin.git